# How to sum up multiple lists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am working on a prolog program, but I have no idea to finish the program. Here is the requirement.

The program allows multiple fact, however, the length of list in each fact **must equals**

Example 1

```
%fact
f(first, [1, 6, 10]).
f(second, [7, 3, 8]).
f(third, [5, 9, 5]).
```

Example 2

```
%fact
f(first, [1,6,10]).
f(second, [7,3,8]).
f(third, [5,9,5]).
f(fourth, [7,3,9]).
f(fifth, [7,7,2]).
```

Example 3

```
%fact
f(first, [1,6,10,54,11,6]).
f(second, [7,3,8,34,2,7]).
```

Now, I need to write a predicate **sum_list()**, so that users can do the following things.

Example 1

```
?-sum_list([first,second,third], Even, Result).
Even = 1
Result = [13,18,23]
```

Example 2

```
?-sum_list([first,second,third,fourth,fifth], Even, Result).
Even = 2
Result = [27,28,34]
```

Example 3

```
?-sum_list([first,second], Even, Result).
Even = 3
Result = [8,9,18,88,13,13]
```

**Result** is a list which contains the sum of each element in the corresponding fact lists.

**Even** is counting the number of even number in the Result, in Example 2, only 28 and 34 are even, so Even = 2.

Thanks.

Thanks for SimoV8's hints, and I get some ideas to solve in the way:

```
%fact
f(first, [1, 6, 10]).
f(second, [7, 3, 8]).

sum_list([Head|Tail], E, R) :- 
    f(Head, P),
    sw(P, Tail, [R]),
    even(E,R).

sw(H1, [Head|Tail], [X|R]) :-
    f(Head,S),
    sum(H1, S, X),
    sw(X, Tail, R).

sw(_, [], []).

sum([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[X|L3]) :- 
    sum(T1,T2,L3), X is H1+H2.

sum([],[],[]).

even(E, [X|R]) :-
    even(E2, R),
    ((X mod 2) =:= 1 -> E is E2; E is E2 + 1).

even(0, []).
```

However, the answer only accepts **two f()**, if more than two f(), it will return **FALSE**

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Actually I am a prolog beginner, there are many prolog things that I don't know. I have an idea to implement this program on java, but I know that there is a big difference between java and prolog(for example I can't use return value in prolog), and that makes me don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum_list([], 0, []).
sum_list([H|T], E, [RH|RT]):- f(H, X), 
                              sum(X, RH), 
                              sum_list(T, E2, RT), 
                              ((RH mod 2) =:= 1 -> E is E2; E is E2 + 1).
 sum([], 0).
 sum([H|T], S1):- sum(T, S2), S1 is H + S2.
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. In example 1, the result is [13,18,23] which is [(1+7+5),(6+3+9),(10+8+5)] {sum up the elements vertically}. However, your answer still give me a hint to solve that question, so thanks a lot.